# Cleanup .throttle()'d callbacks in componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have the following setup:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Dispatcher.on('app:update', _.throttle(this.postLoad, 1000));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Dispatcher.removeListener('app:update', this.postLoad)
}
```

However, I'm receiving errors in the console in regards to trying to call `setState` on a Component that isn't mounted (happens inside `postLoad`). What are my best options to cancel the throttled functions in the `componentWillUnmount`?

`.throttle` is from Lodash.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely seeing your throttled function being called on the trailing edge of the timeout. To illustrate, let's look at the default behavior of [throttle()](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle):

```
var throttled = _.throttle(function() { 
  console.log('ran'); 
}, 1000);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
  throttled();
}

// → ran
// → ran
```

This is strange, there's two calls made to `throttled()`. The loop actually makes three calls, but the expectation is that since it's been throttled to 1 second, there should only be one call.

By default, the trailing option for `throttle()` is set to true. This means that after the timeout has elapsed, the throttled function is called again - assuming it was called after the timeout starts and before it ends.

The simple solution in your case might be turning this option off, as follows:

```
var throttled = _.throttle(function() { 
  console.log('ran'); 
}, 1000, { trailing: false });
```

Comment: I did try this, but it didn't seem to have the desired effect I was after, but thank you, as it did lead me to implement throttle's `cancel` method properly!